# Image upload works, thumbnail is skewed?

Tags: php, image-processing, thumbnails, image-uploading

When uploading to my server the regular image uploads fine but for some images when the thumbnail is being created the mage rotates and I don't know why or what's going on with my code?

Please note I'm using old syntax and I know it's ugly but I'm lazy and it works.

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<? include('header.inc.php'); ?>
<?
    if(isset($_POST['upload_Submit'])) {
     $_SESSION['success'] = 0;
     $upPath = "/home/dolphina/public_html/images/";
     $fileName = uniqid(time().date(mdY));
     $_SESSION['upload_Error'] = 0;
     $error_Log = "<ul>";
      if ($_FILES['upload_Image']['size'] > 10000000) {
       $error_Log .= "<li>image is greater than 10 megabyte</li>";
        $_SESSION['upload_Error'] = 1;
      }
      if (($_FILES['upload_Image']['type'] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES['upload_Image']['type'] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES['upload_Image']['type'] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES['upload_Image']['type'] == "image/png")) {
       if($_FILES['upload_Image']['type'] == "image/gif") {
        $fileExt = ".gif";
        }
       if($_FILES['upload_Image']['type'] == "image/pjpeg") {
         $fileExt = ".jpg";
       }
       if($_FILES['upload_Image']['type'] == "image/jpeg") {
        $fileExt = ".jpeg";
       }
       if($_FILES['upload_Image']['type'] == "image/png") {
         $fileExt = ".png";
       }
      } else {
      $error_Log .= "<li>invalid image type</li>";
      $_SESSION['upload_Error'] = 1;
    }
    if(!$_POST['upload_Caption']) {
      $error_Log .= "<li>no caption entered</li>";
      $_SESSION['upload_Error'] = 1;
    }
    if(!$_POST['upload_Password']) {
      $error_Log .= "<li>no password entered</li>";
      $_SESSION['upload_Error'] = 1;
    }
    if($_POST['upload_Password'] != "3") {
      $error_Log .= "<li>wrong password</li>";
      $_SESSION['upload_Error'] = 1;
    }
   $error_Log .= "</ul>";
    if($_SESSION['upload_Error'] == 1) {
      echo $error_Log;
      $_SESSION['upload_Error'] = 0;
    } else {
      //COPIES TEMP FILE TO PATH
    copy($_FILES['upload_Image']['tmp_name'], $upPath."pics/".$fileName.$fileExt);
    $first=ImageCreateFromJPEG($upPath."pics/".$fileName.$fileExt);
  echo "GOT HERE";
//CREATES AND COPIES THUMBNAIL TO PATH
function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

  /* read the source image */
  $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
  $width = imagesx($source_image);
  $height = imagesy($source_image);

  /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
  $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

  /* create a new, "virtual" image */
  $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

  /* copy source image at a resized size */
  imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

  /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
  imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}
make_thumb($upPath."pics/".$fileName.$fileExt, $upPath."thumb/thumbnail_".$fileName.$fileExt, 300);
//INSERT INTO DATABASE
      $upImage = "INSERT INTO `images` (`url`, `thumb`, `date`, `time`, `ip`, `caption`) VALUES ('images/pics/".$fileName.$fileExt."', 'images/thumb/thumbnail_".$fileName.$fileExt."', CURDATE(), CURTIME(), '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$_POST['upload_Caption']."')";
      $upFINAL = mysqli_query($mysql_conn, $upImage);
      $_SESSION['success'] = 1;
    }
  }
  if($_SESSION['success'] == 1) { echo("<div>SUCCESS</div>");}
?>
<style>
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; margin-left: 4px; }
</style>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<div>File</div>
<div><input type="file" name="upload_Image" size="40"></div>
<div>Caption</div>
<div><input type="text" name="upload_Caption" size="40"></div>
<div><input type="password" name="upload_Password" size="40"></div>
<div><input type="submit" name="upload_Submit" value="Upload Image"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of one of the images that doesn't go well with the thumbnail process?

Comment: Also looks like you use __imagecreatefromjpeg()__ regardless of input format, although that should just fail rather than output borked images.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP documentation, a quote from [comment 112902 on `imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#112902) says this:

> **imagecreatefromjpeg()**
>   This function does not honour EXIF orientation data.  Pictures that are rotated using EXIF, will show up in the original orientation after being handled by imagecreatefromjpeg().

Your thumbnails might simply be showing their original orientation. That's assuming your image viewer actually respects that flag.

Also you should probably not use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` if the input is not jpeg.